# One of the Specific Intuitions behind Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, intuition, central-limit-theorem

This is a relatively vague question since it occurred during the class couple of semesters back when the Professor tried to explain the "intuition" of Gaussian distribution. The information is in incomplete pieces, but I still wish to fully understand this intuition:

Given $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_m$ are i.i.d. random variables, zero mean, unit variance. It was mentioned to us we can look at the normalized sum as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum_{i = 1} ^m X_i \langle (X_1, \cdots, X_m), (\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}, \cdots, \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}) \rangle$ and hence as a projection of a vector onto "some kind" of shell of radius $\sqrt{m}$-I remember this shell was related to the "norm" of the Gaussian vectors:

[image]

Then he mentioned some kind of "typical" normal vector direction, and the projection being fairly close to the typical normal vector. Hence the "uniqueness" of Gaussian distribution etc.

This is all I have so far. I am sorry for the incomplete pieces of information, but I wonder how is this related to the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: If you regard $(X_1, \cdots, X_m)$ as random point in $\mathbb R^m$ and if the $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed, then you can say that the joint distribution is rotationally symmetric about the origin (an abritrary rotation will give the same distribution) if and only if the $X_i \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$.  This then gives an easy way of sampling uniformly from the surface of a hypersphere of radius $r$: generate such a set of $X_i$s and then multiply each by $\frac{r}{\sqrt{\sum X_i^2}}$.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your comment! But how is this related to the CLT?

Comment: Another property of the Gaussian distribution is that it is the limiting distribution in the Central Limit Theorem for suitably rescaled sums of iid random variables with finite variance.  But I would regard this as saying something different from the rotational symmetry.

Comment: One way might be that once you specify the first two moments, the normal distribution has maximum entropy out of all distributions supported on the line. Next, the support and entropy of $\sqrt n(\hat \mu -\mu)$ increases monotonically as a function of $n$. From this point of view, if there were any limiting distribution, it must be the normal.